Durrett Probability page48 Theorem 2.1.12: where is independence used?
I'm reading Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples Theorem 2.1.12(see picture below). The assumption of this theorem is that X and Y are independent. The first part of the theorem says that the expectation is equal to an iterated integration (first wrt $\mu$ and then wrt $\nu$ ). The proof of this result is one line by Fubini's theorem. It seems that Fubini's theorem does not rely on any independence assumption, and it merely states that under mild conditions the double integral is equal to iterated integral. I'm wondering why we need the assumption that X and Y are independent, or where the independence assumption between X and Y is used?


Independence is used in the very first equality of the proof, i.e. so that the law of $(X,Y)$ is $\mu\times\nu$.

Thanks, this is very helpful! Just to clarify, does this mean the Fubini's theorem has implicitly assumed independence? Maybe I'm confused because the book didn't seem to link product measure to independence. On page38 of the book, below theorem 1.7.1 it says the notation $\mu$ is just $\mu_1\times\mu_2$, and the same $\mu$ is used in Fubini's theorem at the bottom of this page. That means in Fubini's theorem, $\int _{X\times Y}fd\mu=\int _{X\times Y}fd\mu_1\times\mu_2$, i.e., the theorem is about two independent random variables. Right?

Fubini's theorem isn't about random variables or probability measures a priori - it's a general theorem of measure theory concerning product measures. The link between product measures and independence of random variables would be a separate result.

You are right! Maybe let me restate my confusion regarding product measures: when working with random variables, is it true that we can use the product measure for the joint measure (law) only when they are independent?  is there a result from Durrett or other reference that states something like two random variables are independent if and only if their joint measure is the product measure? Since Fubini's theorem uses the product measure as said in my last comment, does this mean when we apply Fubini to deal with expectation of a h(X,Y), random variables X and Y must be independent?
